# AllegroGraph SPARQL: DELETE from both the Default Graph and Named Graphs

Tags: sparql, allegrograph, named-graphs

**Using AllegroGraph 6.4.6**

I am trying to generate a single SPARQL DELETE query w/ respect to quads defined:

```js
// Example of dataset used for generation of SPARQL
const quads = [ 
  ['<1>','<2>','<3>'],        // Graph: DEFAULT
  ['<a>','<b>','<c>','<d>'],  // Graph: <d>
  ['<w>','<x>','<y>','<z>'],  // Graph: <z>
]

/* Example of triples being queried against

   S   P   O   G
  --- --- --- ---
  <1> <2> <3>
  <a> <b> <c> <d> 
  <w> <x> <y> <z>        If we delete <1> <2> <3>, we don't
  <1> <2> <3> <4>   <--  want to accidentally delete this quad   

*/
```

---

I'm able to generate a SELECT query for determining the existence of all quads:

```
# Returns all specified quads that exist

SELECT ?s ?p ?o ?g
FROM DEFAULT 
FROM NAMED <d>
FROM NAMED <z>
WHERE {
  {
    ?s ?p ?o.
    VALUES (?s ?p ?o) {
      ( <1> <2> <3> )
    }
  }
  UNION
  {
    GRAPH ?g {?s ?p ?o.}
    VALUES (?s ?p ?o ?g) {
      ( <a> <b> <c> <d> )
      ( <w> <x> <y> <z> )
    }
  }
}
```

- Returns all quads specified in `VALUES`
- `<1> <2> <3> <4>` does not get returned.

---

The next query is an attempt at creating the DELETE query, but has a few issues (Note the **Option 1** and **Option 2** comments):

```
# Should delete all quads specified in VALUES

DELETE { 
  GRAPH ?g {?s ?p ?o.} 
  ?sD ?pD ?oD. 
}
# USING DEFAULT     # Option 1
# USING NAMED <d>   # Option 2
# USING NAMED <z>   # Option 2
WHERE {
  {
    ?sD ?pD ?oD.
    VALUES (?sD ?pD ?oD) {
      ( <1> <2> <3> )
    }
  }
  UNION
  {
    GRAPH ?g {?s ?p ?o.}
    VALUES (?s ?p ?o ?g) {
      ( <a> <b> <c> <d> )
      ( <w> <x> <y> <z> )
    }
  }
}
```

- With ONLY **Option 1** uncommented, an error message is returned:

  ```
  Found DEFAULT. Was expecting one of: NAMED, Q_IRI_REF, QNAME, QNAME_NS.
  ```
- With ONLY **Option 2** uncommented, only the specified Named Graph triples are deleted:

  ```
  DELETED:

   S   P   O   G
  --- --- --- ---
  <a> <b> <c> <d>
  <w> <x> <y> <z>
  ```
- With BOTH **Option 1** and **Option 2** commented, every triple gets deleted, even the triple `<1> <2> <3> <4>` which we weren't trying to delete.

  ```
  DELETED:

   S   P   O   G
  --- --- --- ---
  <1> <2> <3>
  <a> <b> <c> <d>
  <w> <x> <y> <z>
  <1> <2> <3> <4>
  ```

Comment: What's your quad store (name and version)? It matters... Not least, because `DEFAULT` doesn't exist in every store, if indeed in any (though it is in [discussion for possible inclusion in SPARQL 1.2](https://github.com/w3c/sparql-12/issues/43)).

Comment: I'm using AllegroGraph 6.4.6

Comment: The AllegroGraph documentation only [discusses `SELECT` (not `DELETE`) with `FROM DEFAULT`](https://franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/6.3.0/python/tutorial/example010.html). It does say that the "unnamed" `DEFAULT` Named Graph cannot be addressed simultaneously with other Named Graphs, so I think that your quest for a single query for this deletion cannot be satisfied -- and also that you may not be able to delete `{ <1> <2> <3> }` from `DEFAULT` without also deleting `{ <1> <2> <3> <4> }`.

Comment: Add `PREFIX franzOption_defaultDatasetBehavior: <franz:rdf>` or `PREFIX franzOption_defaultDatasetBehavior: <franz:default>` to your query and repeat experiments.

Answer (score 1):

`FROM DEFAULT` to indicate the default graph is not a standard SPARQL feature, so its behavior will be dependent on the triplestore that you use (and many SPARQL engines will simply give a syntax error).

To delete from the two named graphs, you could do this (note that I've removed the `NAMED` bit, and removed the graph parameter):

```
  DELETE {?s ?p ?o}
  USING <d>
  USING <z>
  {
    ?s ?p ?o.
    VALUES (?s ?p ?o) {
      ( <a> <b> <c> )
      ( <w> <x> <y> )
    }
  }
```

Like I said, the `DEFAULT` keyword is not a standard SPARQL feature. Perhaps your SPARQL engine will understand it if you do this:

```
  DELETE {?s ?p ?o}
  USING DEFAULT
  USING <d>
  USING <z>
  {
    ?s ?p ?o.
    VALUES (?s ?p ?o) {
     ( <1> <2> <3> )
     ( <a> <b> <c> )
     ( <w> <x> <y> )
    }
  }
```

Otherwise, your best best is probably to use a sequence of updates, rather than trying to do everything in one big delete.